# No pubspec.yaml file found. in flutter VS Code

Tags: flutter, pubspec

I Want to build project but i always get this error. I know it doesn't because of my code. But i don't understand.By the way i can run the application on emulator pixel 3. But i can't run in terminal. Maybe the terminal affecting the error.

[image: Erorr]

Comment: Are you in the root folder in the terminal?

Comment: I wasn't  thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click `+` and type `flutter run` again. It work for me

[image]

Comment: Thank you mate, but i understand the problem's source. It's about the directory's of my project. I just need to write cd to my project.